# tic-tac-toe logic and syntax using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react.js and I started trying to create a simple Tic-Tac Toe app, but I'm having an issue with my logic.

When I console.log the current turn I have the correct "X" or "O" character tile. However, when I console.log it inside the render() function I get the opposite character tile (i.e. if the winner is "X" then the winner renders on the template as "O").

I tried swapping the value of current value inside the render() function, but it's giving me an error. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Link to my github repo is here, or the check out the code is below.
https://github.com/jchan922/tic-react-toe/blob/master/src/App.js

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

- *CodePen*

  -- http://codepen.io/jchan922/pen/LxKEwm?editors=0010
- *Question clarification*

  -- even though my logic is console logging everywhere else correctly, if the winner is "X" then the winner renders on the view as "O" and vice versa. I can't get my template to render the correct "X" or "O" player.

[image]

```
class App extends Component {
    // Component Initialization
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            player_one: "X",
            player_two: "O",
            currentTurn: "X",
            board: [
                "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
            ],
            winner: null,
            moveCount: 0
        }
    }

    handleClick(index){
        if(this.state.board[index] === "" && !this.state.winner) {
            var currentBoard = this.state.board,
                count = this.state.moveCount;

            currentBoard[index] = this.state.currentTurn;
            count += 1;

            this.setState({
                board: this.state.board,
                winner: this.checkForWinner(),
                currentTurn: this.state.currentTurn === this.state.player_one ? this.state.player_two : this.state.player_one,
                moveCount: count
            });

        }
    }

    handleReset(){
        console.log("RESET")
        this.setState({
            player_one: "X",
            player_two: "O",
            currentTurn: "X",
            board: [
                "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
            ],
            winner: null,
            moveCount: 0
        })
    }

    checkForWinner(moveCount) {
        var currentTurn = this.state.currentTurn;
        var symbols = this.state.board;
        var winningCombos = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]];

        return winningCombos.find(function(combo) {
            if(symbols[combo[0]] !== "" && symbols[combo[1]] !== ""  && symbols[combo[2]] !== ""  && symbols[combo[0]] === symbols[combo[1]] && symbols[combo[1]] === symbols[combo[2]]) {
                console.log("Found a winner", currentTurn, [combo[0],combo[1],combo[2]]);
                return currentTurn;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }

        })
    }

    // Component Render
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.currentTurn);
        return (
            <div className="app-container">
                {this.state.winner ? <h2>{`The winner is ${this.state.currentTurn}`}</h2> : null}
                <div className="board">
                    {this.state.board.map((cell, index) => {
                        return <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} key={index} className="square"><p className="playerSymbol">{cell}</p></div>
                    })}
                </div>
                <div className="reset">
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleReset()} className="resetButton">RESET</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @Chris even though my logic is console logging everywhere else correctly, if the winner is "X" then the winner renders on the template as "O" and vice versa.

Comment: Ah gotcha, let me have  a look. Actually, could you chuck it in a codepen? Makes it easier to debug

Comment: @Chris, here ya go! http://codepen.io/jchan922/pen/LxKEwm?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need `player_one` and `player_two` in your state, just have them as constants, in case you want to have `player_one` as 'O' sometimes I prefer to have a boolean props that controls who plays first and let the parent component handle them(unless `App` is the only component that renders but I don't see anything in your UI that chooses the first one to play).

Secondly since `moveCount` isn't rendered at all why do you have it in your state ? maybe you want to add some rendering for it later.

Now to your problem, let's pretend that it's 'X' turn and that the player clicked the winning click, 'X' won but before that the click fires your `handleClick` function, before the last statement `this.setState(...)` `currentturn` equals `this.state.player_one` which is 'X' but you do this :

```
this.setState({... , currentturn : this.state.currentturn === this.state.player_one ? this.state.player_two : this.state.player_one,...});
```

Which means "if currentturn is X then set it to O , otherwise set it to X", after that because state changed the UI rerenders with `currentturn='O'` , now in your render function you put `the winner is {currentturn}` so it renders `the winner is O`.

The solution is simple, just replace `{currentturn}` with `{currentturn===player_one ? player_two : player_one}`, do this change only where you declare the winner.

Here is the codepen updated : http://codepen.io/abnud1/pen/KajpWN?editors=0010

Comment: thanks! you're correct on the first two points. however, this solution only seems to work for X and not O. Since i'm very new to react, is it best practice to do this logic in the render section? I also tried moving around some of the keys in the this.setState({...}) to see if order matters in the handleClick() method, but nothing happened.

Comment: @justinchanman it worked with 'O' too, you can see the above codepen

Comment: the order of keys doesn't matter, that's not react, that's javascript, as for best practice react is a UI library , there isn't really much place for this kind of logic outside render because this is UI logic, what we can talk about is logic outside the scope of React (business logic that is)

Comment: thanks so much! I figured out that one of my variables was misspelled, which is why it was only showing up as X when i rendered on the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something reusable, for example, code which is possible to use if there will be a board of 4x4 or 5x5 instead of 3x3 you need something like this

Just generate a matrix with `X` and `O` where `X` will be `true` and `O` will be `false`

https://gist.github.com/Hovakimyan/342d579aa22a567d84d92798bf2667a6

Here size will be your board `SIZE` for example `3 | 4 | 5...`

```
  checkMatrixForWin = (matrix) => {
    const angl = [], antiAngl = []
    for (let i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      let rowvalue = null
      for (let j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        if (typeof matrix[j][i] !== 'boolean') break

        if (j === 0) rowvalue = matrix[j][i]

        if (rowvalue !== matrix[j][i]) {
          break
        }
        if (j === SIZE - 1) {
          return matrix[j][i]
        }
      }
      angl.push(matrix[i][i])
      antiAngl.push(matrix[i][SIZE - 1 - i])
      if (matrix[i].every(item => item === matrix[i][0])) {
        return matrix[i][0]
      }
    }
    if (angl.every(item => item === angl[0])) {
      return angl[0]
    }
    if (antiAngl.every(item => item === antiAngl[0])) {
      return antiAngl[0]
    }
  }
```